# How Do I Hide An Iframe If src="about:blank"?

Tags: iframe

I have a situation where I have an iframe overlaying an image slider that needs to be interactive if the iframe src="about:blank". My thinking is to decrease the iframe height to 0 when this is the case so that the z-index setting on the iframe does not interfere with what is beneath it.

I have looked at several similar previous questions in the forum but none of these do exactly what I want. Apologies if this is a very basic issue but I have been struggling with it for days.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  $(function() {
     $('#iframe').load(function() {            
      if($.trim($(this).contents().find("body").html()) == "") {
         $(this).hide();
      }
     });
  });
 </script>
 <iframe id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work since the src="about:blank" seems to be generating <html>, <head> and <body> tag sets within the iframe.